# Intellij 14 and Android AVD

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I've recently upgraded my Intellij to version 14. I wanted to create some Android application so I created a new project. Then I wanted to start an emulator so I used the AVD manager from within Intellij and created a new AVD. But then trying to run the application failed as the AVD couldn't be run.

```
Waiting for device.
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/tools/emulator -avd AVD_for_Nexus_5_by_Google -netspeed full -netdelay none

PANIC: Could not open: AVD_for_Nexus_5_by_Google
```

Now the thing is AVDs created by Intellij are stored in ~/.android/avd whereas those created by AVD manager from Android SDK are in /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/.android and these run fine.

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong, I don't recall having issues with Intellij 13 although I haven't played with Android for a long while now.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue on Ubuntu, Windows 7 and Windows 8 machines. For some reason if you have selected your emulator ABI as x86 or x86_64 then it doesn't start, however, if you select armeabi-v7a, it should start.